# What is the practical difference between full build in Docker file versus only copying output from CI/CD?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I need to create a docker container for an Asp.Net Core application (though the idea is the same for any application in any language) and there are 2 different approaches from what I can see:

From Microsoft docs:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
COPY bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/ App/
WORKDIR /App
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "NetCore.Docker.dll"]
```

From Docker docs:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

From what I can tell the difference is where the build of the application happens: either inside the docker itself or outside docker (in ci/cd tool e.g.) and only the output being copied in the docker file.

Is there any other technical difference/benefit between these approaches apart from the obvious ones of where the build commands are executed? (E.g. one would be faster, more reliable, etc.)

P.S. I plan to run CI/CD inside a containerized environment like Github Actions or Bitbucket pipelines, so the build should not be dependent on local develop settings in any case.

Comment: Answer to your query is what is the purpose of the image that you are building ? Do you want just to provide service at the end by containers prepared by your image (if this is the case then you are looking for runtime, in such cases if someone else is using those images who do not have source-code they can not rectify or improve anything at runtime)  or something else. If you want to provide just a runtime then there is no point in adding a compiler and related libraries in the image.

Comment: The purpose is to create a docker image that will run in test/prod environment. Local development won't need docker at all

Comment: 1st case- build is dependent on the host machine (dependent on the developers settings for compiling) and in 2nd case - it has a standardize build mechanism.

Comment: I'll use bitbucket pipelines or similar to build that will be run inside container so it won't be much dependent on local settings (will add to the question)

Comment: so in this case it will behave exactly same, not much difference between 2 approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I find if you build in the container there's fewer surprises as slight differences between developer machines become irrelevant, but there's a case to be made for both approaches. Sometimes the container build is slower, so you have to settle for a sub-optimal situation.

A build on your dev machine will have access to 100% of the CPU, generally speaking, but in a container it is limited by your Docker settings. Most people usually have that at 50% or less to avoid hogging the whole machine, so it's 50% as fast at best.

So the *more reproducible* approach is to let the container build everything.

The more *performant* approach is to build externally, then quickly package in the container.

Note that this equation changes considerably if you have a low-powered laptop but a very fast build server you can offload the build to. For example, there's no way a 2-core i3 laptop with 8GB can keep up with a 32-core Ryzen or Epyc server with 256GB.

Comment: Yes, I had seen a node build that was way slower that it was compared to a direct build in CI/CD, is it always the case or there is something wrong with setup? Since it will be CI/CD that will build, developer machines won't matter much here I hope, then it will be rather reproducible? I don't plan to develop locally using docker

Comment: If you aren't impatient then it's easier to just dump it in the container and wait for the thing to pop out. This largely avoids the "Works on My Machine™" problem. If you do this a lot and it's an impediment to getting work done then I'd use the compromise approach.

Comment: I plan to run the application locally directly (without docker), so it's only build on the server (build agent) I am considering. So it's way less volatile that a developer machine

Comment: That's the safest approach, and if you have a good build server it can even be faster. You can get a good 12+ core server on a budget these days, which is really nice.

Comment: If you build it in CI/CD outside of Docker and then have an image that just copies in the built artefact you will have to maintain the configuration of the CI/CD (e.g. it having the right version of .net and any other dependencies you might need). If its built in docker, maintaining this is, in my opinion easer (your build server only needs docker and an internet connection) and also makes it easier if you need to have different apps built on different .net versions for example.

Comment: @StefanR I plan to run in bitbucket pipelines or similar, where build already is based on an image, so nothing much to maintain, but to chose the same base build image really. So this bit at least should not be a problem